# Reexpresing a trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry

I was reading a book about spectral analysis in time series and found the following statement without proof.

**Statement**

The function 
$f(r)=a_2^{r/2}\frac{(\sin((r+1)\theta)-a_2\sin((r-1)\theta))}{(1+a_2)\sin(\theta)}$

Can be written as

$$f(r)=a_2^{r/2}\frac{\sin(r\theta+\psi)}{\sin (\psi)}$$

where $\tan(\psi)=\tan(\theta)\frac{1+a_2}{1-a_2}$

Anyone has an idea about how to prove this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}&\frac{\sin((r+1)\theta)-a_2\sin((r-1)\theta)}{(1+a_2)\sin\theta}=\\&=\frac{(\sin(r\theta)\cos\theta+\cos(r\theta)\sin\theta)-a_2(\sin(r\theta)\cos\theta-\cos(r\theta)\sin\theta)}{(1+a_2)\sin\theta}\\
&=\frac{(1-a_2)\sin(r\theta)\cos\theta+(1+a_2)\cos(r\theta)\sin\theta}{(1+a_2)\sin\theta}\\
&=\sin(r\theta)\cot\theta\frac{1-a_2}{1+a_2}+\cos(r\theta)\\
&=\sin(r\theta)\cot\psi+\cos(r\theta)\\
&=\frac{\sin(r\theta)\cos\psi+\cos(r\theta)\sin\psi}{\sin\psi}\\
&=\frac{\sin(r\theta+\psi)}{\sin\psi}
\end{align}$$